# Collation so ordering doesn't work properly with postresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql

I am developing a rails app  which has its content in Turkish. I am using Postgresql 9.2.2 as my database backend. Everything works fine (no weird character issues etc. ) except for proper ordering.

For example, when I try to list some items that are ordered by city they are in, I expect something like "Adana, Bursa, İstanbul, Giresun, Zonguldak ..".

Instead, I always get Turkish specific characters at the end/beginning of the list. (i.e."Adana, Bursa, Giresun, Zonguldak, İstanbul")

I have initialized my postgres db with command: `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8 --locale=tr_TR`

when I `\l` in psql console I get the expected.

```
 Name              Owner         Encoding   Collate   Ctype
 ----------------+-------------+----------+---------+-------+ 
 app_development | app         | UTF8     | tr_TR   | tr_TR |
 app_production  | app         | UTF8     | tr_TR   | tr_TR |
 app_test        | app         | UTF8     | tr_TR   | tr_TR |
 postgres        | monkegjinni | UTF8     | tr_TR   | tr_TR |
```

I also tried to create databases manually with `LC_CTYPE="tr_TR.UTF-8"` and `LC_COLLATE="tr_TR.UTF-8"`, and again no progress.

Some information about my development environment:

- Running Mountain Lion 10.8.2 with Macbook Pro 7.1
- `psql --version`  : 9.2.2
- `rails --version` : 3.2.11

`$ locale` :

- LANG="tr_TR.UTF-8"
- LC_COLLATE="tr_TR.UTF-8"
- LC_CTYPE="tr_TR.UTF-8"
- LC_MESSAGES="tr_TR.UTF-8"
- LC_MONETARY="tr_TR.UTF-8"
- LC_NUMERIC="tr_TR.UTF-8"
- LC_TIME="tr_TR.UTF-8"
- LC_ALL=

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you get a different result between postgres and the operating system `sort` command with the same data and same locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 locales on OS X are broken.  You can try to use a non-UTF-8 locale (tr_TR.ISO8859-9), but it appears that it is also broken in this respect.  So it's not going to work.

Comment: As you mentioned, I have tested it out on production and It works as expected. King Regards for this.